# Acces Web inspector compatible with Windows?

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, safari, web-inspector

I want to debug my code because it doesn't work on Safari IOS7 (but work with Safari Windows).

So, i have :
- activate Web inspector on my Iphone4 
- connect Iphone on my PC (windows 7)

On Safari (Windows), in the dev menu, my Iphone does not appear.

On Itunes, my Iphone appear.

It's compatible with Windows?

Thanks,

Comment: I've been having the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35714766/470749

Answer (score 0):

It's a functionality provided by Safari 6 and followings, and Safari 6 isn't proposed on Windows plateforms.